# Catch FCM notification message in service worker after click_action triggered

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

The issue, I am facing with notification messages is, that a new tab is opened, whenever the complete URL of the defined click_action is not matching any opened tab.

Assuming click_action equals `mydomain.com` and there is an opened tab with the URL `mydomain.com/anyroute`. A new tab is opened, because the URLs do not match. But I would like the already opened tab to be focused instead of opening a new tab.

Can a notification message be catched by the service worker after a user clicks on the message or is there any other possibility?

EDIT: So far, the service worker's events like `onBackgroundMessage` or `notificationclick`are not passed, since the push notification is if type `notification_message`.

Comment: Do you use the firebase sdk for push notications or did you write your own handler for them in your service worker?

Comment: Thanks for your message! I use the SDK

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `on` like explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive#setting_notification_options_in_the_service_worker).

```
messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
  console.log(
    "[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ",
    payload
  );
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = "Background Message Title";
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: "Background Message body.",
    icon: "/firebase-logo.png",
  };

  // Loop trough all clients controled by the SW
  self.clients.matchAll(options).then(function (clients) {
    // Let's see if we already have a chat window open:
    const url = new URL(client.url);

    if (url.pathname == "/custom_url/") {
      // Excellent, let's use it!
      client.focus();
    }

    // do something with your clients list
  });

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});
```

Where you can use `self.clients` to loop trough all tabs/clients of your app that are controled by the SW. You can focus to a specfic client if the url/patch matches.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But unfortunately this event handler is not passed because of the message type ```notification_message```. With the type ```data_message``` your solution would maybe work, but not in this case